# How to get textField id in 'doneButtonAction' method while using multiple numPad keyboard textFields in swift?

Tags: ios, swift, keyboard, textfield

I'm using two textField which is of numPad keyboard type. I have added `Next` button for the first textField and `Done` button for the second textField in the numPad keyboard. Using the following code.

```
import UIKit

class SecurityPinSettingsVC: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate
{
@IBOutlet weak var textField1: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var textField2: UITextField!
 override func viewDidLoad()
    {
        super.viewDidLoad()    
        self.textField1.delegate = self
        self.textField2.delegate = self
        self.textField1.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.center
        self.textField2.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.center
        addNextButtonOnKeyboard()
        addDoneButtonOnKeyboard()        
    }
func addNextButtonOnKeyboard()
    {
        let nextToolbar: UIToolbar = UIToolbar(frame: CGRect(x: 0,y: 0, width: 320, height: 50))
        nextToolbar.barStyle       = UIBarStyle.default
        let flexSpace              = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: UIBarButtonSystemItem.flexibleSpace, target: nil, action: nil)
        let next: UIBarButtonItem  = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Next", style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.done, target: self, action: #selector(ViewController.doneButtonAction))


        var items = [UIBarButtonItem]()
        items.append(flexSpace)
        items.append(next)

        nextToolbar.items = items
        nextToolbar.sizeToFit()

        self.textField1.inputAccessoryView = nextToolbar
    }



    func addDoneButtonOnKeyboard()
    {
        let doneToolbar: UIToolbar = UIToolbar(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 320, height: 50))
        doneToolbar.barStyle       = UIBarStyle.default
        let flexSpace              = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: UIBarButtonSystemItem.flexibleSpace, target: nil, action: nil)
        let ddone: UIBarButtonItem  = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Done", style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.done, target: self, action: #selector(ViewController.doneButtonAction))

        var items = [UIBarButtonItem]()
        items.append(flexSpace)
        items.append(ddone)

        doneToolbar.items = items
        doneToolbar.sizeToFit()

              self.textField2.inputAccessoryView = doneToolbar
    }
 func doneButtonAction()
{
        //self.textField2.becomeFirstResponder()
        //self.textField2.resignFirstResponder()
}

}
```

Both buttons are successfully added. The problem is, I could not create separate action methods for `Next` button and `Done` button. It accepts only `doneButtonAction` method for both buttons, which I have created and used in previous viewControllers. So, How can I get the textField id in the `doneButtonAction` method, in-order to know which button is clicked. So that, by clicking on `Next` button I want to make textField2 to become first responder, and by clicking `Done` button I want textField2 to resign first responder.

Like in ordinary textField, `textFieldShouldReturn` method will do this job easily, where the textField object will be passed to that function as an argument.

Here, how can we pass the textField object to the `doneButtonAction` method.

I'm using Xcode 8.2, Swift 3.0

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Try out this library, really useful, dont need to code anything -> pod 'IQKeyboardManager'

Comment: Is it possible in your case to add `sender` to the `doneButtonAction`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can get text field which are become responder

```
if textField1.isFirstResponder {
    // textfield 1 is becomeResponder 
}
```